# после смены владельца не открывается сайт

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

Здравствуйте. Сайт работал нормально, внес изменения в шаблон, и решил залить эти изменения по sftp. Но вышла ошибка нет прав. Потом нагуглил, и у папки с сайтом сделал владельца user вот этим кодом `sudo chown -R user /home/user` после этого вылезла ошибка что сайт не может записать инфу в `/home/user/site.name/public_html/storage`,я установил права `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`, и после всех этих манипуляций, сайт не открывается. `Сайт site.name пока не может обработать этот запрос. HTTP ERROR 500` что я запорол?) Знаю что это ошибка php,но логи не могу найти.
По ssh открывается, а по домену и айпи нет. Как исправить?

Comment: А что лог апача говорит? `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @E_p `[Wed Oct 12 21:46:17.434063 2016] [:error] [pid 10429] [client 141.8.142.19:35628] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/user/site.name/public_html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/user/site.name/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/` и там много такого. Понятно что нет прав, но я ведь ставил `chmod -R 777 storage` почему он жалуется?

Comment: `sudo chown -R www-data /home/user/site.name/public_html/storage `

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что пользователь не совпадает с используемым веб-сервером юзером. Например, нужен юзер www-data. 
В любом случае надо смотреть конфиг сервера.
Если это апач, что в httpd.conf прописан путь до лога, по дефолту лог находится в

> `/var/log/apache2`

Можно попробовать зайти по ssh набрать команду:

> `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` (или какой-то другой путь,
>   указанный в конфиге)

и послать запрос серверу, думаю ошибка обнаружится достаточно быстро.

Еще лучше посмотреть права на файлы:

> `ls -l /home/user/site.name/public_html/`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Проблема вроде в этом была) В комменте выше ответ

Comment: @Alex_01 отметьте ответ если он верный